# Toast from onProgressUpdate not showing up

Tags: android

Everything is working fine but the Toast from the onProgressUpdate is not showing up. I am surely doing something wrong. Please help me out.
The Code is:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Sending...");
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.projectyourself.96.lt/android.php");
        //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yembed.in/loans4you/form.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", params[0]));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return "fail";
        }
        return "sent";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String i) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(i);
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {
        if(r=="sent") {
            t.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
            else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Not Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: call inside runOnUiThread

Comment: @kishorejethava onProgressUpdate is called on the main thread already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in the method onProgressUpdate(String... values) has to be an array. You created a whole new method that is never actually called.

To fix your problem, change this:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String i) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(i);
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

to this:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... i) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(i);
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),i[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```